# Select query to return no records

Tags: sql, db2

I have Table 1 : EMP as below

```
   ID   NAME             CITY             AMT        
   -------------------------------------------
    1   sajani           Bangalore        20          
    2   Prashanth        Bangalore        10          
    3   Jayvin           Bangalore        10
```

Table 2: EMP1

```
ID   NAME1            CITY1            AMT1    
 ---------------------------------------------
  1   Sajani           Bangalore        10      
  1   Sajani           Bangalore        10      
  2   Prashanth        Bangalore        10      
  3   Jayvin           Bangalore        10
```

ID is the Key and is common in both the files. I want a Select SQL statement which states table 1 = table 2 and once select query is executed, it should return 0 records.

Comment: Can you please share your attempt at writing the SQL query? What did you write, and what specifically you are facing issue with? Also please add more context for both the tables, why are you duplicating the same information in multiple table?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result.

Comment: What if `table2` has employees not in `table1`?

Comment: what means table1=table2? exactly same rows with the same value? what occurs when there are duplicate row ( for exemple in table 2)? what occurs when rows in a table does not exist in other table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I figured out the solution

```
Select * from emp                                               
where amt <>(
              select sum(e1.amt1) 
              from emp1 e1 
              where e1.id =emp.id
             )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MINUS operator

```
SELECT ID, NAME, CITY, AMT
FROM EMP

MINUS

SELECT ID, NAME1, CITY1, SUM(AMT1)
FROM EMP1
GROUP BY ID, NAME1, CITY1
```

Comment: No. For sets A - B can be equal to zero (empty set) when there are elements in B not present in A. You need `A - B union B - A = empty set`.

Comment: @astentx that's your interpretation of OP's problem and data, not mine. Seeing her own answer, that is indeed what she was looking for. My answer is thus correct

Comment: If you think OP has enough experience and test cases to cover all the situations, this of course is a better approach than with subquery. But as long as the purpose of SO is not one-time questions, but something valuable for the future, the above query does not tell that table A equals to (aggregated) table B (ignoring the fact that key should be unique)

Comment: This is my interpretation of the question as well.

Comment: @astentx you are not wrong. But after a few years here I have learned : 1. to read between lines on new-comers questions and detect that they have hard to correctly express their problem. 2. To know what is a one-time question (and answer) and what might serve the community. Here chances are  high that its more a one-time question and answer. And now look what happened: She is gone forever without a thanks, a comment, a +1 (txsGordon!), or an accepted answer. Her solution is lame performance-wise and mine is much better, but she doesn't care. It not worth the time to answer more than this ;)

Comment: @ThomasG Yes, I agree with you)